# How to redirect old url of php to new ur of codeigniter using .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

My old url like

```
http://www.mywebsite.in/abc.php
```

My new url like

```
http://www.mywebsite.in/abc
```

Here's my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have convert my core php project to codeigniter and I have configure in my config.php file I have set my base url and remove index.php from url and also set all url through route.php file. Now, I want to redirect my old url of core php with new url of codeigniter. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: can any body help me plssss

Comment: What error are you facing is it redirect or not? and which server you using?

Comment: when I search my website on google it shows and when I click on a particular link it shows me old url with 404 error this is  because I have convert my core php project into codeigniter.

Comment: if your server is GoDaddy `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` it should work

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# To externally redirect without .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally rewrite to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```